# Pandas count the unique values of column 1 (Table A) if column 1 (Table B) exists in column 2 (Table A)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 tables as shown below:

```
df_1
title     column_a
    a     {"blabla","dog","cat"} 
    a     {"aaaa","apple","dog"}
    a     {"abcde","apple","cat"}
    b     {"qwert","dog","apple"}
    c     {"bbbbb","dog"}
```

2nd table

```
 df_2 
 category
      cat
      dog
    apple
```

I would like to create a new column on df_2 to count the **unique values** of df_1["title] based on df_2["category"] that exists in df_1["column_a"]. Outcome that I want is shown as below:

```
 df_2 
 category  unique_count_of_title
      cat                      1
      dog                      3
    apple                      2
```

I tried some research but most of the answer told me to groupby based on "column_a" but in my case won't work as multiple values exists in a single row. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Waht is `print (type(df['column_a'].iat[0]))` ?

Comment: its <class 'str'>

Comment: not sure if that's the issue? Coz couldn't get the answer as expected from your solution below

Comment: Is possible use `df_1['column_a'] = df_1['column_a'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution? Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert strings repr of sets to sets:

```
import ast

df_1['column_a'] = df_1['column_a'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with convert sets to lists and for count unique values is used [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
s = (df_1.assign(column_a = df_1['column_a'].apply(list))
         .explode('column_a')
         .groupby('column_a')['title']
         .nunique())
```

Last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) fo rnew column:

```
df_2['unique_count_of_title'] = df_2['category'].map(s)
print (df_2)
  category  unique_count_of_title
0      cat                      1
1      dog                      3
2    apple                      2
```

Another solution with `defaultdict` and length of sets for dictionary called `d1`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in df_1[['title','column_a']].to_numpy():
    for val in b:
        d[val].add(a)

print (d)
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'dog': {'a', 'c', 'b'}, 'cat': {'a'}, 
                            'blabla': {'a'}, 'aaaa': {'a'}, 
                            'apple': {'a', 'b'}, 
                            'abcde': {'a'}, 'qwert': {'b'}, 
                            'bbbbb': {'c'}})

d1 = {k:len(v) for k, v in d.items()}
df_2['unique_count_of_title'] = df_2['category'].map(d1)
print (df_2)
  category  unique_count_of_title
0      cat                      1
1      dog                      3
2    apple                      2
```

Comment: The 1st solution works like a magic! Can I know what's the use of this code:
import ast

df_1['column_a'] = df_1['column_a'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

Comment: @ChngFongChia - it convert strings to sets.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [Pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# reproduce the input data
import pandas as pd
df_1_data = {'title': ['a','a','a','b','c'], 
             'column_a': [{"blabla","dog","cat"}, {"aaaa","apple","dog"}, {"abcde","apple","cat"}, {"qwert","dog","apple"}, {"bbbbb","dog"}]}
df_2_data = {'category': ['cat', 'dog', 'apple']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1_data)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2_data)

# unpack the sets into columns
df_1 = df_1.set_index('title')['column_a'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).reset_index()

# pivot the columns into rows
df_1 = df_1.melt('title')

# merge both dataframes and count uniquely, grouping by the desired column
s = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on = 'value', right_on = 'category').groupby('category')['title'].nunique()

# update the original dataframe with the unique counts
df_2['unique_count_of_title'] = s[df_2.category].values
    category    unique_count_of_title
0   cat         1
1   dog         3
2   apple       2
```